# Alignment of the values in the table

Tags: regex, perl

```
Test.txt
tom 
cat=0  bat=1  mat=0  pen=1
ironman122_bore.1 
cat=8e-7  bat=8.001e-7  mat=5e-6  pen=200.001e-6     
batmanbegin_nice.1  
cat=10  bat=1  mat=0.25  pen=49.25
```

Here a sample of my input and I expect my output to be like in Out.txt

```
Out.txt
name                cat       bat       mat       pen               
tom                 -         1         -         -    
ironman122_bore.1   8e-7      8.001e-7  5e-6      200.001e-6
batmanbegin_nice.1  10        1         0.25      49.25
```

here is what I tried

```
my $pr = "%-12s"; 
my @headers = qw/name cat bat mat pen/; 
my %names; 
while (<DATA>) {     
    chomp;     
    my $line = <DATA>;     
    %{$names{$_}} = split /=|\s+/, $line; 
}  
printf $pr x @headers . "\n", @headers; 
for (keys %names) {     
    my @ds = ($_);     
    for my $k (@headers[1..$#headers]) {
       my $v = $names{$_}->{$k};         
       push @ds, $v ? $v : '-';     
    }     
    printf $pr x @ds . "\n", @ds; 
}
```

But I get an output as

```
name          cat       bat       mat       pen               
tom        -         1         -         -    
ironman122_bore.1  8e-7      8.001e-7  5e-6      200.001e-6
batmanbegin_nice.1  10         1         0.25     49.25
```

How can I modify the code so as to get the aligned output as shown in Out.txt?
I was not able to achieve what I expected when I used my actual data which looks similar to what I have given as an input.

**EDIT:** The sample input has been changed along with the expected result

Comment: add `\t` to your format string

Comment: this works for me with the Data you provided. My guess would be, that there are some spaces in the input data that you code does not filter, especially behind the names.

Comment: No the thing is it gives equal spaces after the 1st element in a line. i.e. if it gives 10 spaces after the 1st element then the values will not be alligned if the length of the 1st element varies.

Comment: @tauli i have edited my sample input, can u check if this works even for this

Answer (score 0):

**With Earlier Data**

The code posted works fine for me.

**Output**

```
name        a           b           c           d           e           
bobby       60          74.2        8           -           10.25       
tom         10.1        2           300.89      4145        55
```

Is the font you are viewing it in fixed-width?

---

**With New Data**

The reason for the misalignment is that some of the items under the 'name' column exceed 12 characters (e.g. 'batmanbegin_nice.1' is 18 chars long).

[`(s)printf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) will not truncate the string to 12 chars the way it's been specified in the original post.

To truncate, specify a `.` between the `%` and `12`:

```
printf '%.12s', 'batmanbegin_nice.1' ;  # "batmanbegin_"
```

If truncation is not desired, increase the string length to `%20s`.

As for dynamic detection of max length, that warrants another question :)

Comment: @unkaitha : Either the sample data you have provided is inconsistent with your actual data or your code is different. When I run what's been provided it pads correctly.

Comment: i think what you told about the sample data is true. I will post the same kind of data as of my actual data.

Comment: the input provided is closest to my actual input for which i am not getting a proper allignment, can u check if this code works even for this???

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);

my $pr = "%-24s";
my @headers = qw/name/;
my %names;
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    s/^\s+//g;
    s/\s+$//g;
    my $line = <DATA>;
    $line =~ s/^\s+//g;
    $line =~ s/\s+$//g;
    %{$names{$_}} = split /\s*=\s*|\s+/, $line;
}
push @headers, uniq sort map { keys %{$names{$_}}; } keys %names;
printf $pr x @headers . "\n", @headers;
for (keys %names) {
    my @ds = ($_);
    for my $k (@headers[1..$#headers]) {
        my $v = $names{$_}->{$k};
        push @ds, defined $v ? $v : '-';
    }
    printf $pr x @ds . "\n", @ds;
}

__DATA__
 tom
cat = 0  bat =1  mat= 0  pen=1
ironman122_core.1
 cat= 8e-7  bat= 8.001e-7  mat= 5e-6  pen= 200.001e-6
batmanbegin_core.1
cat=10  bat = 1  mat= 0.25  pen= 49.25
```

output:

```
name                    bat                     cat                     mat                     pen                     
tom                     1                       0                       0                       1                       
batmanbegin_core.1      1                       10                      0.25                    49.25                   
ironman122_core.1       8.001e-7                8e-7                    5e-6                    200.001e-6
```

Comment: The code i have tried was also suggested by you for some other question @cdtits ... can u suggest some changes in the previous code itself?????

Comment: I still have that problem of allignment... Dont know what the problem is.   Can i fix the number of spaces for each column so that the next column will start only after the number of spaces fixed????

Comment: the input provided is closest to my actual input for which i am not getting a proper allignment, can u check if this works even for this

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to pad any string for aligned output is using sprintf.
E.g.: You want 2 Columns evenly sized at 20 chars with a seperator. You also want your right Column to be left aligned and padded after your specified text. No Problemo:

```
print sprintf("# %20s | %-20s #","Column1","Column2")."\n";
```

Would print:

```
username@hostname:~$ perl -e 'print sprintf("# %20s | %-20s #","Column1","Column2")."\n";'
#              Column1 | Column2              #
```

Comment: This looks good but can i continue till 5 columns??? And what am i supposed to give in "coulmn1" and "coulmn2" for my example???

Comment: You may wan't to read the reference for printf/sprintf.
@ChrisCharley: I chose sprintf because it doesn't actually print, but return the formatted string for further use (e.g. writing it to a file). TMTOWTDI.